# how to submit() a form with js without opening it in new window, when onclick() was with shift key?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I/m trying to submit form in iframe "frameTarget"
I have a form like this

```
<Form name="FEdit" method="post" target="frameTarget">
    <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="">
</Form>
```

somewhere on page is a button

```
<button onclick="DoSmth()">edit</button>
```

and I have a js code, that submits this form

```
function DoSmth(){
    document.FEdit.submit();
    //setTimeout("document.FEditStarter.submit()",1000); //same result =(
}
```

The problem is, when I click this button with SHIFT key pressed, this form opens in a new window, not in iframe with name "frameTarget".

What to do to not open it in a new window?

Comment: Don't submit it but script it into the iframe or a div with ajax

Comment: @kalpaitch: I'm glad to, but users don't =)

Comment: maybe check it for a pressed SHIFT key and don't submit if pressed?

Comment: Why do you mind? Pressing SHIFT on submission will cause the form to submit to a new window. That's expected behaviour, and the user who did it is expecting for that to happen. Why hinder his user experience?

Comment: @EL2002: If you really have to submit it on the target frame, you'll have to add a `keyup` event listener and submit the form only if the SHIFT key is released.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answering to myself =)

```
if(!event.shiftKey){
//then do submit()
}else{
//do smth else (warn about new window, for example)
}
```

(of course if there'snt a way to switch shiftKey event to "false" state for browser)